# Apple Pay web using c# (testing on ngrok)

Tags: c#, ios, ngrok

I am trying to test my Apple pay application using **ngrok**. However, the merchant validation fails and I don't get the required token. The Apple pay button is visible on the iPhone that, I am using for testing.
I have used this link to create a sample application: https://github.com/justeat/ApplePayJSSample

I have got the following (as instructed in the above URL)

1. The pfx file (placed in the project path)
2. The merchant validation txt file (placed in .wellknown folder)
3. The domain is verified in the apple pay website

Can some one suggest how to test the application? Or the possible reason why the merchant validation is failing?

What should be the requestUri (is it different for test and Prod?) and can the display name be any thing or is it certificate specific?

```
JsonDocument merchantSession;
                if (!ModelState.IsValid ||
                    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model?.ValidationUrl) ||
                    !Uri.TryCreate(model.ValidationUrl, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri requestUri))
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
                // Create the JSON payload to POST to the Apple Pay merchant validation URL.
                var request = new MerchantSessionRequest()
                {
                    DisplayName = _options.StoreName,
                    Initiative = "web",
                    InitiativeContext = Request.GetTypedHeaders().Host.Value,
                    MerchantIdentifier = _ApplePayServieBusiness.GetMerchantIdentifier(),
                };

 

                merchantSession = await _ApplePayServieBusiness.GetMerchantSessionAsync(requestUri, request, cancellationToken);
```

**UPDATE:**
I have put my steps that I used for MerchantValidation in the below link. However, I am still not able to hit onpaymentauthorized function in site.js
https://github.com/justeat/ApplePayJSSample/issues/68#issuecomment-795687727

Comment: I have tested the application like this https://github.com/justeat/ApplePayJSSample/issues/68. Could some one please tell me the right way to debug/test?

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the pfx on the request. It's not enough to have it in the project folder. Using c# I did it like this :

```
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    var certFile = new X509Certificate2("Your file path", "your key");           
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certFile);           
    
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
    {                 
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("your url", "your request");
    }
```

The specifics of the code depend on how you choose to send the request. Here I am using httpClient.PostAsync. If you want/need to use a different method you will need to adjust the code accordingly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).